# Not able to persist data correctly in local storage with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I use a mix of `useContext` and useEffect to persist `useContext` data in local storage. I am failing to do so because of a conditional render. The case here is that I want to have a sign-in button when the user is not logged in and a log-out button when the user is logged in.

In the Codesanbox, I have fixed the sign-in button in the modal to change the initial null state of "user" to "User is logged in".

In `SignInDialog.js`, I have a `useEffect` to which, as a dependency value, I pass the `isOpe`n prop of the sign-in modal. So each time it opens and closes, it should log "useEffect setItem 2". Testing with just opening the modal and closing it by clicking on the side brings a successful result. After I press the sign-in button in the modal, the modal closes, but `useEffect` is not triggered.

The value of "user" is then used in the parent component to conditionally render either the 'sign in' or 'log-out' button.
I have narrowed down the problem to the conditional rendering in `Main.js`.

When I remove it, everything works as expected. The problem seems to be with rendering the order of parent and child components. I can't think of a way to fix that issue without changing my approach.

**UserContext.js**

```
import { createContext } from "react";

export const UserContext = createContext(null);
```

**App.js**

```
export default function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <UserContext.Provider value={{ user, setUser }}>
        <Main />
      </UserContext.Provider>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Main.js**

```
export default function Main() {
  const { user, setUser } = useContext(UserContext);

  const logOut = () => {
    setUser(null);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {/* If I only have SignInButton and no conditional render it works  */}
      {/* <div>
          <SignInButton />
      </div> */}

      {user ? (
        <div>
          <Typography>{user}</Typography>
          <Button onClick={logOut}>Log out</Button>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <div>
          <SignInButton />
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

**SignInButton.js**

```
const SignInButton = () => {
  const [openSignInDialog, setOpenSignInDialog] = useState(false);

  const handleSignInClickOpen = () => {
    setOpenSignInDialog(true);
  };

  return (
    <StyledEngineProvider injectFirst={true}>
      <div>
        <Button onClick={handleSignInClickOpen}> Sign in </Button>
        <SignInDialog open={openSignInDialog} setOpen={setOpenSignInDialog} />
      </div>
    </StyledEngineProvider>
  );
};
export default SignInButton;
```

**SignInDialog.js**

```
export default function SignInDialog(props) {
  const { user, setUser } = useContext(UserContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(">>>>>>>useEffect getItem 1");
    /* const data = window.localStorage.getItem('uli')
    console.log(`data = ${data}`) */
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(">>>>>>>useEffect setItem 2");
    /* window.localStorage.setItem('uli', user) */
  }, [props.open]);
  {
    /* end goal is to pass user as dependency but left like this for testing purposes */
  }

  const test = () => {
    setUser("User logged in");
    props.setOpen(false);
    {
      /* props.setOpen(false) doesn't make no difference */
    }
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    props.setOpen(false);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Dialog open={props.open} onClose={handleClose}>
        <Box component="form">
          <DialogTitle>Sign in data</DialogTitle>
          <DialogContent>
            <DialogContentText>username, password..</DialogContentText>
          </DialogContent>
          <DialogActions>
            <Button type="button" onClick={test}>
              Sign in
            </Button>
          </DialogActions>
        </Box>
      </Dialog>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit angry-fast-upe615]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `SignInDialog.js`, you are setting the local storage in that `useEffect` with `props.open` as a dependency. But when you call `props.setOpen(false);` in `test`, `SignInDialog.js` get removed from the screen; hence your `useEffect` is never running. You could change `test` as below and remove that `useEffect`:

```
const test = () => {
  let user = "User logged in";
  setUser(user);
  localStorage.setItem("uli", JSON.stringify(user));
  props.setOpen(false);
};
```

Then, in `App.js`, change your `user` definition as below, so earlier at this point, you retrieve what's within local storage if there is one:

```
const [user, setUser] = useState(
  localStorage.getItem("uli") ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("uli")) : null
);
```

[image: Edit angry-fast-upe615]